# Insertion order and Duplicate Keys in Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.7.
I have a dictionary something like this.

```
dict = { 'a' :2 , 'a' :1 , 'b':3 , 'c':4}
print(dict) 
O/P ={'a' : 1 , 'b' :2 , 'c':3 }
```

Now In python 3.7 dictionary must maintain insertion order .So expected o/p will be {'a':2 , 'b':3 , 'c' :4} , but ('a',2) is being removed from dictionary instead of('a',1) .Why is this happening ??Is there any rule for removing duplicate keys in python ??

Comment: Ty sir , I wasn't knowing old value gets deleted .

Comment: Since dict is the name of a python builtin class, you should'nt use it as the name of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

From the Python documentation:

> The main operations on a dictionary are storing a value with some key and extracting the value given the key. It is also possible to delete a key:value pair with del. If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten. It is an error to extract a value using a non-existent key.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining insertion order is concerned with *different* keys:

```
>>> dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}  # do NOT shadow built-in name 'dict'
>>> print(dct)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
# and not
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}  # which was totally possible before Python3.6
```

When receiving multiple values for the *same* key, the last one provided wins:

```
>>> dct = {'a': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> print(dct)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

This is similar to the following scenario:

```
>>> dct = {}
>>> dct['a'] = 3
>>> dct['a'] = 1
>>> dct['b'] = 2
```

Would you expect `dct['a']` to be `3` now because of the "insertion order"? Certainly not!

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to a key can be anything and even duplicated since it merely a value. Keys however, are similar to a variable name. Like in many programming languages, if a variable name is used again in the same scope or method, the first variable and its value is overwritten by the second since it is more recent.

In this case it may be more appropriate to to assign a different key (think of keys as identifiers) to the same value if that is your wish. Like this

```
dict = { 2: 'a', 1: 'a', 3:'b', 4:'c'} 
print(dict)
O/P = {1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'c'}
```